# Upload file through php and ajax for input not inside form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table with data. At the end of each row i have an edit button. When i click on it, through javascript i change all columns of this row to text areas and user can edit the values. Then a save button appears and if user clicks on it, data is saved through ajax to sql database.

This works successfully but i want to add an extra column for file upload and i cannot get the file to the php file through ajax. Here is my code:

HTML CODE:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Image</th>
<th colspan="3">Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="1" class="update" data-id="1" data-column="title">Mr</td>
<td id="lastname_val1" class="update" data-id="1" data-column="last_name">Doe</td>
<td id="image_val1" class="update" data-id="1" data-column="image"><img src="mypic.png" id="imgsrc_1"></td>
<td id="edit1"><input type="button" class="edit_button" id="edit_button1" value="edit" onclick="edit_row(1);"></td>
<td id="save1"><input type="button" class="save_button" id="save_button1" value="save" onclick="save_row(1);"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function edit_row(id)
{
 var lastname=document.getElementById("lastname_val"+id).innerHTML;
 var photo=document.getElementById("image_val"+id).innerHTML;
 var title=document.getElementById("title_val"+id).innerHTML;


 document.getElementById("lastname_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='lastname_text"+id+"' value='"+lastname+"' >";
 document.getElementById("title_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='title_text"+id+"' value='"+title+"' >";
 document.getElementById("image_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='file' id='image_text"+id+"' name='imgInp_"+id+"' style='display:none;'  />"+document.getElementById("image_val"+id).innerHTML;
 $('input#image_text'+id).attr('value', $('#invpiceditimg_'+id).attr('src'));

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="block";

}

function save_row(id) {
var fd = new FormData();
var file = $("#img_text"+id)[0].files[0];
fd.append("lastname", document.getElementById("lastname_val"+id).innerHTML);
fd.append("id", id);
fd.append("myfile", file);
fd.append("photopath", document.getElementById("image_text"+id).value);

$.ajax
    ({
      type:'post',
      url:'imagechg.php',
      data: fd,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
    </script>
```

PHP CODE(imgchg.php):

```
<?php
   $lastname = test_input($_POST['lastname']);
   $id= test_input($_POST['id']);
   $photopath= $_POST['photopath'];

   $uploaddir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."\\img\\upload_pics\\";
   $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
   $check = getimagesize($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"]);

   $newfilename = $lastname.$id;

   if($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"] != "") {
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploaddir . $newfilename);
?>
```

Now, if i try to echo variables that are posted through ajax, i see them normally but if i try to echo $uploadfile, i get blank value and of course file is not being uploaded.

Comment: check your console and use php's error reporting, I think you'll find your answer/reason.

Comment: Woah please add validations to your file upload module. As it is Trojans and other harmful files can easily be uploaded.. Properly get the mime type..  For php `5.3+` use `finfo()` class

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code, there error in console
index.html:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

I don't see in code element with id = "img_text" but I can see element with id="image_text"
So try to change $("#img_text"+id) to $("#image_text"+id)